# Java Pattern Matcher COMMA

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to use a pattern check against a string, and for some reason it is saying that strings that shouldn't match, do..

Code:

```
private static final Pattern VALID_TOKEN = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9\\{\\}\\[\\].+-/=><\\\\*]*$");
System.out.println(VALID_TOKEN.matcher(token).matches());
```

Examples:

```
"123" = true
"1,3" = true // Should NOT BE TRUE
"123*123" = true
"123*^123" = false
```

All of the above examples are correct except "1,3"  the pattern should not include a COMMA.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the dash in

```
+-/
```

Otherwise, it is interpreted as a range from `'+'` to `'/'` - a range that includes `'+'`, `','`, `'-'`. `'.'`, and `'/'`.

```
private static final Pattern VALID_TOKEN = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9\\{\\}\\[\\].+\\-/=><\\\\*]*$");
//                              Here ------------------------------------------------^^
```

Alternatively, you can move the dash to the end of the character class (i.e. put it before the closing `]`).